# Splitting a wav file using C

Tags: c, split, block, wav

I want to use C to break a wav audio file into evenly spaced blocks. How could I do that? Are there any libraries that I could use (i'd prefer not to but I will if I have to)?

Comment: You have to understand the structure of such files to be able to do that. If you know how data is stored inside wav file, add that to question.

Comment: ... so just store bytes chunks?

Comment: the structure of a wav really isn't complicated. google the structure of a wav headder

Comment: @saadtaame Any good resources that you could point me toward?

Comment: @camelccc But I'm not sure how to split that data. I'm on osx and I get question marks for data values

Comment: This might help: http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_LoadWAV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ffmpeg` library will help you. you can do anything related to video and audio!.
Also see the following article maybe help you.
[A Simple C Class to Manipulate WAV](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29676/CWave-A-Simple-C-Class-to-Manipulate-WAV-Files)